# What's the meaning of a red x-sign on Chrome tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, ux

I guess it's a Chrome thing and not coming from the website as I can't see that icon in DevTools / Application / Images

If I duplicate the tab, the duplicated one has the standard github icon. Also there are no errors in DevTools / Console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub shows a red cross or a green tick mark when you're viewing a Pull Request page, depending on whether the PR is mergeable or whether it has failed any CI tests.

Websites can dynamically change their favicons, and GitHub's pull request pages automatically receive live updates as CI tests run. It is likely that the page did not have any indicator at first, but added it later using JavaScript based on such a live update.

If you "Duplicate" a tab in Chrome, the new tab is loaded using the cached data as the webpage was *originally* retrieved from the server – but it will not have any of the JavaScript-based dynamic updates applied to it.